# How to use methods within match statements before using the match arm's associated value?

Tags: rust

I'm looking for a workaround/solution to a problem I've encountered at least a couple times. It occurs when matching to an enum member of a struct, where depending on the match, different (mutating) methods may be called on the struct before the enum's associated value is used. The methods require a mutable reference to the struct, which disallows usage of the enum's associated value afterwards. Trivial example:

```
struct NonCopyType {
    foo: u32
}

enum TwoVariants {
    V1(NonCopyType),
    V2(NonCopyType)
}

struct VariantHolder {
    var: TwoVariants
}

impl VariantHolder {
    fn double(&mut self) {
        match &mut self.var {
            TwoVariants::V1(v) => {
                v.foo *= 2;
            },
            TwoVariants::V2(v) => {
                v.foo *= 2;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let var = TwoVariants::V1( NonCopyType {
        foo: 1   
    });
    
    let mut holder = VariantHolder {
        var
    };
    
    match &mut holder.var {
        TwoVariants::V1(v) => {
            holder.double();
            println!("{}", v.foo); // Problem here
        },
        _ => ()
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5a9f8643546d08878bb5fabe5703d889

This can't be allowed because the variant may have been changed and `v` may not even make sense as a value any more. This occurs even if the method does not modify the variant at all; as long as you have to call a mutable method for any reason before using the enum's associated value (say, to mutate a different member which is used in a calculation with the associated value), the borrow checker errors out compilation.

There are two workarounds I can think of. First is to use a second match statement, separating the method calls from the value usage. This I don't like because it separates the logic. Second is to use a nested `if let` within the match arm. This is a little better, even if by then I'm 3 tabs deep for what should be a a relatively simple operation.

However, my preferred solution would be to not rematch against the enum at all. Is there a way I can leverage `unsafe` to access the enum's associated value without checking the variant? (or any way at all I can avoid rematching after calling a mutating method?)

Comment: If you always know the variant and for some bizarre reason really don't care about safety and can ensure soundness yourself, you can just use [`union`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/unions.html) directly, this kind enum is nothing else but tagged union itself, and validation of correct tag is exactly what match in this case does. There's no way to extract the value by yourself from enum though, only union. Of course, you could try to just transmute the enum into target type if you're feeling adventurous, but its most certainly UB as you have no guarantees for enum layout here.

Comment: Why don't you remove the fields from the enum values (e.g. change to `enum TwoVariants { V1, V2 }`) then store `foo` in a struct or tuple with the enum instead? (e.g. `(TwoVariants, u32)`)

Comment: The general way to do this via unsafe is to acquire a pointer in a valid location (`let ptr : *mut T = &value as *const T as *mut T`), then use that pointer whenever you please (`&mut(*ptr).method()`, in case of an exclusively borrowing method). This does not check for lifetimes and ownership. Of course you should not, under no circumstances, use unsafe code in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Understanding the Problem

Compilation of your code yields:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `holder` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> temp.rs:38:13
   |
36 |     match &mut holder.var {
   |           --------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
37 |         TwoVariants::V1(v) => {
38 |             holder.double();
   |             ^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
39 |             println!("{}", v.foo); // Problem here
   |                            ----- first borrow later used here
```

So we cannot have 2 mutable borrows. Observe that we are not modifying `holder.var`, we can get away with an immutable reference. Change the `match &mut holder.var` into `match &holder.var` and compile, we get:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `holder` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutab
le
  --> temp.rs:38:13
   |
36 |     match &holder.var {
   |           ----------- immutable borrow occurs here
37 |         TwoVariants::V1(v) => {
38 |             holder.double();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
39 |             println!("{}", v.foo); // Problem here
   |                            ----- immutable borrow later used here
```

So the compiler prevents us from performing a mutation (`holder.double();`) while the immutable reference (`v` of `holder.var`) is still in use. Just like you've mentioned,

> This can't be allowed because the variant may have been changed and v may not even make sense as a value any more.

However, we, the programmer, have made the following *rule*: **`holder.double()` can only modify `v`; all other fields should remain the same.** E.g. `holder.double()` can do `v.foo = 13`, but cannot do `self.var = TwoVariants::V2(...)`. If the *rule* is followed, there should be no problem to access `v` after calling `holder.double()`, since it is still the same `v`, only that the `v.foo` has changed.

Now the question is, how to access `v` after calling `holder.double()`?

## An Unsafe Solution

As pointed out by L. Riemer in the comment, you can use raw pointers with unsafe constructs. Modify the `match` expression in `main` function to the following code and it should compile:

```rust
match &holder.var {
    TwoVariants::V1(v) => {
        // Create a pointer pointing to v.
        let pv = v as *const NonCopyType;
        
        holder.double();

        // Dereference the pointer, then create a reference to v.
        let v = unsafe { &*pv };

        // Access v as usual.
        println!("{}", v.foo);
    },
    _ => ()
}
```

Note that **THIS METHOD IS STRONGLY DISCOURAGED**, because the compiler cannot guarantee the validity of the data pointed by `pv` at compile time, and there is no runtime error detection too. We just *assume* that the `v` gotten from dereferencing `pv` is the original `v` and `holder.double()` will always follow the *rule*.

To illustrate the point, try to compile with the modified `VariantHolder::double()`:

```rust
fn double(&mut self) {
    match &mut self.var {
        TwoVariants::V1(v) => {
            v.foo *= 2;

            // Assume that we accidentally perform some operations that modify
            // self.var into TwoVariants::V2.
            self.var = TwoVariants::V2(NonCopyType { foo: v.foo + 1 });
        },
        TwoVariants::V2(v) => {
            v.foo *= 2;
        }
    }
}
```

We can see that it compiles fine. `3` will be printed if you run it, that means `v` is actually an element of `TwoVariants::V2` after calling `holder.double()`, not the original `v` anymore.

This kind of bug that compiles fine and produces no runtime error is very hard to spot, pin down and fix. If you add in heap allocations and threads into the system, things will become much more complicated, who knows which operation will break the *rule* and invalidate `pv`.

## A (safe) RefCell Solution

Recall that our *rule* only allows modification of `v`. One workaround is to utilize the [Interior Mutability Pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) with `std::cell::RefCell`:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct NonCopyType {
    foo: u32
}

enum TwoVariants {
    // Wrap NonCopyType in RefCell, since this is the start of modification 
    // point allowed by our *rule*.
    V1(RefCell<NonCopyType>),
    V2(RefCell<NonCopyType>)
}

struct VariantHolder {
    var: TwoVariants
}

impl VariantHolder {
    // Remove mut, telling the compiler that the `double()` function does not
    // need an exclusive reference to self.
    fn double(&self) {
        match &self.var {
            TwoVariants::V1(v) => {
                // Borrow mutable from v and modify it.
                v.borrow_mut().foo *= 2;
            },
            TwoVariants::V2(v) => {
                v.borrow_mut().foo *= 2;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Create a RefCell to contain NonCopyType.
    let var = TwoVariants::V1(RefCell::new(NonCopyType {
        foo: 1   
    }));
    
    let mut holder = VariantHolder {
        var
    };
    
    match &holder.var {
        TwoVariants::V1(v) => {
            // Now `double()` only borrow immutably from `holder`, fixing the 
            // "borrow as mutable while immutable reference is still alive"
            // problem.
            holder.double();

            // Borrow from v.
            let v = v.borrow();

            // Access v as usual.
            println!("{}", v.foo);
        },
        _ => ()
    }
}
```

In essence we are telling the compiler about our *rule*, i.e. In the `double()` function, `holder`, `var`, and `TwoVarients` are immutable, only `v` is mutable.

The advantage of this approach over the `unsafe` one is compiler can help us to make sure our *rule* is followed. Accidental modification in `double()` such as `self.var = TwoVariants::V2(...)` will result in compile error. `RefCell` enforces the borrowing rule at runtime, which will `panic!` immediately if violation of the rule occurs.

## Difference Between Using RefCell and If-Let Solutions

There are some subtle differences between the `RefCell` solution and `if let` solution. The `if let` solution may look something like this:

```rust
match &holder.var {
    TwoVariants::V1(v) => {
        holder.double();
        
        // Use if-let to unpack and get v from holder.var.
        if let TwoVariants::V1(v) = &holder.var {
            // Access v as usual.
            println!("{}", v.foo);

        } else {
            panic!("*Rule* violated. Check `holder.double()`.");
        }
    },
    _ => ()
}
```

1. The checking of our *rule* is performed in runtime, instead of compile time like the `RefCell` solution.
2. If you do `self.var = TwoVariants::V1(NonCopyType { ... })` inside `VariantHolder::double()`, the `if let` clause will still extract `v` out successfully. However, this extracted `v` is no longer the original `v`. This fact is important if the `NonCopyType` has more than 1 field.